# dataUrl is undefined for chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, function (dataUrl) { ... })

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

Problem Description:
In the mv3(manifest version), I'm using the captureVisibleTab function to capture the screen but it's return undefined to me. the dataUrl return undefined.

I've declared the activeTab in the permission and also mentioned the "host_permissions": and "optional_host_permissions": but still got the Unable to capture screen: Either the '<all_urls>' or 'activeTab' permission is required.

but the same function captureVisibleTab is running fine for me in the mv2(manifest version 2). dataUrl return "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AADSKJRgABAQQHJDKABBA"
for mv2 the permission was "<all_urls>

Comment: Please upload the entire extension somewhere, like Github. From your description, it's hard to tell what you've actually done. Or at least create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example The best way to talk about code, is by showing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem with MV3 or chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab, because the following configuration works correctly.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>

</html>
```

myscript.js

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab((dataUrl) => {
  console.log(dataUrl);
});
```